# Hide one item from combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Destination Vault Member set:

```
cboDestinationVault.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumVaultType))
        .Cast<enumVaultType>()
        .Select(x => new { 
            Value = x, Description = x.ToString().Replace("_", " ") 
        }).ToList();

cboDestinationVault.DisplayMember = "Description";

cboDestinationVault.ValueMember = "Value";
```

I want to hide one item from cboDestinationVault.

Comment: If you don't want something in your list, why are you adding it there?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `Where` clause to your `Linq` statement

```
cboDestinationVault.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumVaultType))
        .Cast<enumVaultType>()
        .Where(e => e != enumVaultType.Whatever)
        .Select(x => new { 
            Value = x, Description = x.ToString().Replace("_", " ") 
        }).ToList();
```

if there is more than one you could use `Except`

```
cboDestinationVault.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumVaultType))
        .Cast<enumVaultType>()
        .Except(new []{enumVaultType.ThisOne, enumVaultType.ThatOne})
        .Select(x => new { 
            Value = x, Description = x.ToString().Replace("_", " ") 
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213, sorry i miss my main problem in above. Actually i am using above code only for loading of combo box, then i want to hide one item (after loading in another method)